# Копия данных для fetch. Вывод этих данных

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, fetch, promise

Есть код

```js
    let items;

    fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => (items=data));
        
    console.log(items);
```

В результате `console.log` выдает `undefined`.

1. Почему так происходит?

Я хочу присвоить переменной `items` данные из `https://fakestoreapi.com/products`, полученные с помощью `fetch`. **Так** `items = fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products').then(res => res.json())`; **не получится. Как переменной вовне присвоить нужное значение?** **Мне нужно иметь копию данных, полученных с помощью fetch.**

2. Как записать в переменную вовне результат извлечения данных? Есть функция `fetch`. Как записать результат функции `fetch` в переменную (наподобие `items`), находящуюся **во вне** (так чтобы `console.log` (тоже **вовне**) этой переменной выводил результат функции `fetch`)?

Пытался запустить такой код

```js
let items;

    items = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(res => res.json())

     console.log('Extract items ', items);
```

но получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выдает undefined (последняя строка в выводе - Items  undefined, впереди вывод результата другого кода, который был раннее, до приведенного ). Как быть ( @Grundy )?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149578/discussion-on-question-by-vlad-dv----fetch---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.